# WPF Clickable Links in Text

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, textbox

I have a textbox that display some messages...

```
        <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Center"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          TextWrapping="Wrap"
          FontFamily="{StaticResource LatoRegular}"
          Foreground="Black"
          FontSize="{StaticResource FontSizeRegular}"
          Text="{Binding Message}"
           Background="Transparent"
           BorderThickness="0"
           Padding="0"
           Margin="0"
           IsReadOnly="True"
                                       />
```

If user sent a link in the message, i would wish to be able to detect and click it and open up the page on the browser.

**My situation:
My message could contain other texts or even more than 1 link. E.g "Hi Please visit google.com for more info". i would want the google.com to be recognize as a link and be clickable.**

Anyone have any idea how can i do it?

Or else beside textbox what else can i use.. i need it to blind to the message behind

Comment: How do you know that the message which is sent is a link? Is there any property or do you have to guess from the message?

Comment: i do not know if the message contain a link a not, it is up to the user to post a link

Comment: Please check the updated answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a TextBlock instead of a TextBox in the following way:

```
<TextBlock>
        <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Message}" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}"/>
        </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

Hyperlink_RequestNavigate: will be your event handler where you will open the browser through Process.Start

```
private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

This will be the basic implementation, for your requirement where you don't know whether the user will send a link or some text -

1. Have two controls in the same place:

   a. One simple text block to display text which is not a hyperlink.

   b. One hyperlink text block shown above.
2. Create a flag for the visibility for each of the controls, validate the message when the user sends and set the flag based on whether the message is a link or just plain text.

Or

You can also define a data template for the text block which will change to a hyperlink or a normal text block based on some flag which you need to set after validating what message the user has sent whether it is a hyperlink or a just plain text.

Comment: ur method could work if i have only a link in the message, but my situation is the message could contain other texts or even more than 1 link. E.g "Hi Please visit google.com for more info". i would want the google.com to be recognize as a link and be clickable.